# How do I prevent the page from unloading before the user has confirmed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, magnific-popup

I have the popup appearing but the page continues to unload.
How can I prevent the page from unloading until either the `.js-close` is clicked or the form in my popup is submitted?

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        const newsSubscribePopup = $('#news-subscribe-popup');

        if (newsSubscribePopup.length) {
            $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                    src: newsSubscribePopup,
                },
                type: 'inline',
                preloader: true,
                modal: true,
                showCloseBtn: false,
            });
        }
    };
});`
```

Comment: This is not how beforeunload works. You are supposed to cancel the event, and return a _text string_ as message to show to the user in the confirmation dialog. This dialog is created by the browser itself, you are not supposed to try and show your own HTML modals, popups or stuff like that using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the confirm() function with onclick handler.
Here are simple example:

```
<div class="js-close" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?">action</div>

$('.js-close').on( "click", function() {

      var choice = confirm($(this).attr("data-confirm"));

      if (choice) {
        alert('ok');
      }else{
        alert('no');
      }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spbjqvgw/

Comment: Note that this will not work in a `beforeunload` event as the OP is asking for.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as OP wants it on confirmation i think there are no need for `beforeunload`

Comment: There 100% is if they need to ask for confirmation before the user navigates aways from the page without clicking a link.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Maybe! There are no response for 2 hours . .. Need wait for OP

Comment: this isn't going to work as I need to show a custom popup to show